# How to properly set up backend for private resources for a MERN app using NGINX/AWS

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, mern, http-status-code-405

I want to know how nginx should be set up, knowing I have the MERN App set up on AWS EC2, and my DB is running on MongoDB Atlas. I'm lost on how the back and front ends are communicating with nginx.

Specifically where I should be inserting my IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and how I should be setting up the location blocks to access my APIs because right now either I get a 404 or a 405. I've tried setting the error_page 405 to 200, but that won't work for my situation as users need to be authenticated to access certain resources. Everything worked and was accessible on localhost.

My APIs are structured as /api/auth/signin (signup, resetpass, forgotpass) Right now my backend is running at port 8080. For the react client they are set up as http://ec2-IPv4-address/login (register, reset, forgot)

server.js

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dbConfig = require("./app/config/db.config");
const config = require("./app/config/auth.config");

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static("client/build"));

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const db = require("./app/models");
const Role = db.role;

db.mongoose
  .connect(config.mongoURI
    , {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connect to MongoDB.");
    initial();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Connection error", err);
    process.exit();
  });

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to Off Strength" });
});

// routes
require("./app/routes/auth.routes")(app);
require("./app/routes/user.routes")(app);

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = config.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});

function initial() {
  Role.estimatedDocumentCount((err, count) => {
    if (!err && count === 0) {
      new Role({
        name: "user"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }

        console.log("added 'user' to roles collection");
      });

      new Role({
        name: "moderator"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }

        console.log("added 'moderator' to roles collection");
      });

      new Role({
        name: "admin"
      }).save(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }

        console.log("added 'admin' to roles collection");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

My NGINX default.conf file

```html
server {
#listen       80;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
    access_log /home/ubuntu/client/server_logs/host.access.log main;


    location / {
    root   /home/ubuntu/client/deploy;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    }


    }

    location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:27017;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /home/ubuntu/server;
    }

    server_tokens off;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is too broad - ask more specific questions. Theres plenty of guides how to configure each component of your MERN stack. Few pointers - `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:27017;` - nginx is trying to talk to node on localhost 27017 instead of 8081. The HTTP 405 errors could be related to `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` not including all the verbs your apps trying to use (PUT etc)?

Comment: Thanks for that. It helped steer me in the right direction. I will ask a more specific question.